# Do separate subtab apps operate in the same context / transaction / memory?

Tags: apex, visualforce, subtab-apps, custom-profile

Clicking around subtab apps in a custom profile UI is very quick, leading me to believe that they are operating in the same transaction context. This has implications for how I architect fetching data with lazy instantiation. Anyone know if each controller in a subtab app page operates in its own context or shared context across controllers?